# Como evitar que se copien etiquetas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo un campo de texto que al pegar texto de otras páginas web también se copian las etiquetas HTML y viene con CSS. Quisiera saber como evitar que se copien las etiquetas de cualquier página.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.contenedor-panel').on('click','.panel-ficha', function(){
        var t = $(this);    //t es panel-ficha
        var tp = t.next(); //tp es panel-aspecto
        var p = t.parent().siblings().find('.panel-aspecto');
        tp.slideToggle();
        p.slideUp();
    });

    $('.contenedor-panel').on('click', '.panel-aspecto-descripcion', function(){
        var t = $(this);
        var tp = t.next();
        var p = t.parent().siblings().find('.panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores');
        tp.slideToggle();
        p.slideUp();
    });
    
    $('.editar').on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        // let editar = $(this).parent().prev();
        // editar.attr("contentEditable","true");
        // editar.focus();
    });

    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    let panelAspectoDescripcionIndicadores = 
    '<div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas">'+
        '<div class="puntaje">'+
            '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div>'+
            '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div>'+
            '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div>'+
            '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div>'+
            '<div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="observacion">'+
            '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div>'+
            '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div>'+
            '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div>'+
            '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div>'+
            '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div>'+
            '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div>'+
            '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div>'+
            '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i">i</div>'+
            '<div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="pregunta">'+
            '<div class="pregunta-contenedor">'+
                '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA</div>'+
                '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox">'+
                    '<select class="comboBox">'+
                            '<option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>'+
                            '<option value="Alta">Alta</option>'+
                            '<option value="Media">Media</option>'+
                            '<option value="Baja">Baja</option>'+
                    '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>'+
                '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>'+
                '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>'+
                '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>'+
                '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div>'+
                '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i"></div>'+
                '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos">'+
                    '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar">'+
                    '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarPregunta" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<input class="btn-pregunta" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA PREGUNTA">'+
    '</div>';

    $('.btn-crearElemento').on('click', function(){
        $('.panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores').html(
            panelAspectoDescripcionIndicadores
        );
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-categoria', function(){
        let actual = $(this);
        let btn_categoria_actual = actual.prev();
        $(btn_categoria_actual).html(
            panelAspectoDescripcionIndicadores
        );
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-pregunta', function(){
        let actual = $(this);
        actual.prev().append(
            '<div class="pregunta-contenedor">'+
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA</div>'+
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox">'+
                '<select class="comboBox">'+
                        '<option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>'+
                        '<option value="Alta">Alta</option>'+
                        '<option value="Media">Media</option>'+
                        '<option value="Baja">Baja</option>'+
                '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>'+
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>'+
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>'+
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>'+
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div>'+
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i"></div>'+
            '<div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos">'+
                '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar">'+
                '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarPregunta" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'
        );
        
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.editarPregunta', function(){
        let actual = $(this).parents('.pregunta-contenedor').children('.pregunta-preguntaInicial').attr('contentEditable','true').focus();
        //actual.attr('contentEditable','true');
        
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.eliminarPregunta', function(){
        let actual = $(this).parent().parent();
        actual.remove();
    });

});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  /*CONTENEDOR*/
  .contenedorTotalPreguntas {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  /*PUNTAJE*/
  .puntaje {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    background: #3c8dbc;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .puntaje-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .puntaje-descripcion {
    width: 41%;
  }
  
  .puntaje-puntuacion {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /*OBSERVACIONES*/
  .observacion {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ecf0f5;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  
  .observacion-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .observacion-descripcionInicial {
    width: 33%;
  }
  
  .observacion-puntuacion {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  .observacion-descripcionFinal {
    width: 16%;
  }
  
  .observacion-i {
    width: 4%;
  }
  
  .observacion-malo {
    background-color: #fb86af;
  }
  
  .observacion-regular {
    background: #fbd386;
  }
  
  .observacion-bueno {
    background: #cdf69d;
  }
  
  .observacion-muyBueno {
    background: #cdf69d;
  }
  
  .observacion-acciones {
    /* width: 4%; */
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  /*PREGUNTA*/
  .pregunta {
    /* font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #333;
        height: 55px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center; */
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-contenedor {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    /* height: 49px; */
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-hijo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 49px;
  }
  
  .pregunta-preguntaInicial {
    /* display: flex; */
    display: block;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    /* justify-content: flex-start; */
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-align: justify;
}
  
  .pregunta-comboBox {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /**/
  select {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  option {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /**/
  
  .pregunta-radioButton {
    width: 8%;
  }
  
  /**/
  input[type="radio"] {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /**/
  
  .pregunta-text {
    width: 16%;
  }
  
  /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
  
  .text {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 230px;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
  }
  
  /*text esta dentro de .pregunta-text*/
  
  .pregunta-subirArchivo {
    width: 4%;
  }
  
  .pregunta-iconos {
    /* width: 4%; */
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  /**/
  .pregunta-iconos img {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  /**/
  
  /*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/
  
  .btn-pregunta {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  /*btn-pregungta esta afuera del contenedor "pregunta"*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>index 6</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="index6_2.css">
    <!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedorTotalPreguntas">
        <div class="puntaje">
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-descripcion">PUNTAJE</div>
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">1</div>
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">2</div>
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">3</div>
            <div class="puntaje-hijo puntaje-puntuacion">4</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="observacion">
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionInicial">OBSERVACIONES</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion">IMPORTANCIA</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-malo">MALO</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-regular">REGULAR</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-bueno">BUENO</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-puntuacion observacion-muyBueno">MUY BUENO</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-descripcionFinal">OBSERVACIONES</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-i">i</div>
            <div class="observacion-hijo observacion-acciones">ACCIONES</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pregunta">
            <div class="pregunta-contenedor">
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-preguntaInicial">AQUI PUEDE COLOCAR SU PREGUNTA</div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-comboBox">
                    <select class="comboBox">
                            <option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>
                            <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
                            <option value="Media">Media</option>
                            <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-radioButton"><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="rButton"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-text"><input class="text" type="text"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-subirArchivo"><input class="subirArchivo" type="submit" value="i"></div>
                <div class="pregunta-hijo pregunta-iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarPregunta" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarPregunta" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn-pregunta" type="submit" value="AGREGAR UNA PREGUNTA">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso podrias añadir un listener para escuchar el evento "paste" y capturar el texto plano e insertarlo manualmente.

```js
document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]").addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
});
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px  #aeaeae;
    padding: 5px;
}

div[contenteditable]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content: "Pegar Aqui";
}
```

```html
<div style="color:red">Texto <em>con etiquetas</em> <span style="font-size:1em">HTML para copiar</span></div>
<div contenteditable placeholder="Pegar aqui"></div>
```